# Has anyone ran into BigQuery Notebooks running a lot slower than Colab/Jupyter

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-colaboratory, slice, cpu

I am running python code in BQ Notebooks and find it painfully slow to even return 10 rows of a 100 row dataframe (over 1 min). I can't even slice a dataframe using [0:10]. I have to use .head(10). I know I could run bq code in Colab but I am creating new tables that sync directly in BQ from my code, so I thought it was more ideal to run Notebooks within BQ. So why would the same datasets run a lot slower in BQ Notebooks than Colab and/or are there any strategies to lessen the processing needed to return a slice of a dataframe? For the record, df = df.head(10) is maybe just as fast as Colab but df.head(10) is WAYYY slower in BQ than Colab.

df.head(10) should take half a second instead of a minute.